# Проверить динамический checkbox на checked

Tags: checkbox, javascript

Мне необходимо выводить чекбоксы на экран таким способом

```
  var postB = document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML;
  postB ='<input type="checkbox" id="bla">blablabla<br>';
  document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = postB;

<p id="elem"></p>
```

и я их удачно вывожу. 
Но после нажатия (к примеру кнопки) мне нужно проверить их на checked(тру или фолсе).
В данном случае это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#somecheckbox').is(':checked')) {
        // нажат
    } else {
        // не нажат
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но необходимо управиться без jQ.

Comment: прям таки **необходимо** ? вот что я вам скажу, когда вы будете иметь хотя-бы представление, когда необходимо, а когда вам кажется, что необходимо (читаем - *мне/моему начальнику захотелось повытрепываться* , вы таких вопросов вообще задавать не будете. 

    document.getElementById('bla').checked

Comment: но у вас это работать скорее всего не будет, т.к. с вероятностью 99.99% вы выводите в документ несколько элементов с одинаковым id, что противоречит стандарту html.

Comment: 1)Спасибо за мораль.  Если бы это было так легко, я бы не спрашивал. 
2)Я скинул упрощенный вариант кода,  на самом деле id для каждого чекбокса генерируется уникальное.

Comment: а кнопку вы тоже генерируете ? если да, то лучше не innerHTML делать а document.createElement(); и вешать на него обработчик (checkbox тоже генерировать и проверка тогда будет mycheckbox.checked). в общем тут мало кода, сделайте jsfiddle с кнопками типа "сгенерировать post", и вашей кнопкой где нужна проверка, тогда можно что-то советовать. [типа так](http://jsfiddle.net/zd9ct/)

Comment: спасибо, вариант 
document.getElementById('bla').checked
вполне подошел. я изначально так планировал, но  как-то не работало. оказалось в кавычках дело было.